# Laravel session suddenly not being saved

Tags: laravel

Yesterday it was working fine, but somehow today it's not saving the array to the session.

```
    if(Session::get('header')) {
        $array['header'] = Session::get('header');
    } else {
        $header = $this->loadElements(2, false);
        $array['header'] = $header;
        Session::put('header', $header);
    }
```

When I look in the storage\framework\sessions folder, the header is in the latest session file.

But what looks very weird to me, is that when having the browser window still open, on each page reload a new session file is created, which is very odd to me.

I did some further testing and it has nothing to do with my code, but all with the recreation of sessions after each page load. In another project it works fine, so it must have to do with the recreation.

Why is Laravel all of a sudden not reading the session file and thus recreating it?

In config\session.php I changed `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file')` to `database` and back, and then it works again.

Smh

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your code to use Session::has in your condition rather than get.

```
if(Session::has('header')) {
    $array['header'] = Session::get('header');
} else {
    $header = $this->loadElements(2, false);
    $array['header'] = $header;
    Session::put('header', $header);
}
```

Comment: This is indeed a nicer solution, but not a solution why Laravel suddenly doesnt use sessions and on every page load creates a new session file, until I made a small modification to session.php and reverted it to work again